# How to find $\lim\limits _{n\to \infty }(n[\frac{5}{n}])$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits

> how to find
>
> - $$\lim _{n\to \infty }(n[\frac{5}{n}])$$
> - $$\lim _{n\to \infty }([n]\frac{5}{n})$$

what I did :

$$\frac{5}{n}-1\le[\frac{5}{n}]\le\frac{5}{n}$$

so: $$\lim _{n\to \infty }(n(\frac{5}{n}-1))\le\lim _{n\to \infty }(n[\frac{5}{n}])\le\lim _{n\to \infty }(n\frac{5}{n})$$

we  get :
$$-\infty\le\lim _{n\to \infty }(n[\frac{5}{n}])\le5$$

so this don't work any other idea how to solve it ?

but for the second one this work

$$n-1\le[n]\le n$$

so: $$\lim _{n\to \infty }((n-1)(\frac{5}{n}))\le\lim _{n\to \infty }([n]\frac{5}{n})\le\lim _{n\to \infty }(n\frac{5}{n})$$

we  get :
$$5\le\lim _{n\to \infty }(n[\frac{5}{n}])\le5$$

$$\implies \lim _{n\to \infty }(n[\frac{5}{n}]) = 5$$

thanks

Comment: $[\frac{5}{n}]=0$ for $n>5$.

Comment: What is $\lfloor .1 \rfloor$?

Comment: @MarkViola  $=0$

Comment: @JohnB  do u mean for $n \to \infty , [\frac{5}{n}] = 0$ so the answer for the first one is $0$ ?

Comment: Indeed. -------

Comment: $$\lim_{n\to \infty}(n\times 0)=\lim_{n\to \infty} (0)=0$$

Comment: i got it thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for $n>6$ implies  $0<\left[\frac5n\right]<1 $ then we have $$\left[\frac5n\right] = 0\implies n\left[\frac5n\right]=0 \implies \lim_{n\to\infty}n\left[\frac5n\right]=0$$

on the other hand We have  $[n]=n$
 hence  the other limit is trivially 5.

Answer (score 1):

Sequence for $$a(n)=n[\frac{5}{n}] \to 5,4,3,4,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,\cdots$$
$$a(n)=[n]\frac{5}{n} \to 5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,\cdots$$

Comment: I suggest you to add $n[\frac5n]$ and $[n] \frac5n$ on the RHS--from [review](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/950908)

Comment: @GNUSupporter I made my answer minimalistic on purpose, but your comment fills the gap.

Answer (score 0):

1) Clearly $\left(n\left[\dfrac{5}{n}\right]\right)=0$ for $n\gt 5$
 so the required limit is equal to $0$.

2) On the other hand $[n]\left(\dfrac{5}{n}\right)=\dfrac {[n]}{n}\cdot5$ and $\dfrac {[n]}{n}$ tends clearly to $1$ so the asked limit is equal to $5$.